# Fabric Crashlytics Welcome window won't go away

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I was trying to accept the new terms and service of Fabric, so I logged in to Fabric. I get this window that won't go away!
[image]

I figured that it is mandatory to install crashlytics, so I started installing it, which pointed me to this page:
https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

I reached this step to install my keys

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" <FABRIC_API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET>
```

per this picture
[image]

I clicked on the login link next to it but was faced with the 1st picture from above.

I can't go around that window, what should I do to get rid of that screen so I can view my dashboard!?

Comment: Thanks. Can you enable debug mode, https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html and cause a test crash by pressing play in Xcode, closing the app int the simulator and relaunching it, causing a test crash, and then pressing play again. Let me know how it goes :)